# R:Binary matrix for all possible unique results

Tags: r, matrix, binary, binary-matrix

How to generate a binary matrix for all possible
permutations of 'i' variables X, where " i " can be any
number between 1 and infinite. Resultant matrix will have 2^ i unique rows.

For i=2 , variables x1, x2 each with a possible value of 1 or 0,
so the resultant matrix would be:

```
X1 X2
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Is there any function in R to generate ?

I tried with below function:

```
   matrix(rbinom(160, 1, 0.5),ncol=5,nrow=(2^5))
```

But the result does not show all possible values.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `expand.grid`:

```
 expand.grid(c(0,1),c(0,1))
  Var1 Var2
1    0    0
2    1    0
3    0    1
4    1    1
```

More generally, with 5 columns for example, giving `m`:

```
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(5*2, 1, 0.5),ncol=5))
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  0  1  1  0  0
2  0  1  1  0  0

dim(expand.grid(m))
32 5
```

Comment: `expand.grid(lapply(1:n, function(x) c(0, 1)))` can work for a general solution, where `n` is the number of variables.

Answer (score 3):

The fonction combos of the package hier.part will do the job I think.

```
require(hier.part)
combos(2)$binary
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    1

combos(3)$binary
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
[4,]    1    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1
[6,]    0    1    1
[7,]    1    1    1
```

Except that you will have to add the "null" combination.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
i =2
install.packages('gtools')
library(gtools)
permutations(2,i,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```