# Generate the complete sample space for Binomial distribution for value for n and k?

Tags: python, r, algorithm, simulation, binomial-theorem

I wanted to create the complete sample space of Binomial distribution for a given value of n & k. So `Bin(n = 4, k =2)` should return something like:

```
1 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 
1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 1
```

Comment: You migh be looking for `?combn` -- `combn(n, k, tabulate, nbin = n)`

Comment: A similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368072/create-combinations-of-a-binary-vector)

Comment: @Cath : `combn` is, already, present in an answer in the linked QA

Comment: hi thanks for redirecting me to the original question answered it perfectly