# R- Find Unique Permutations of Values

Tags: r, sorting, combinations, permutation

I am hoping to create all possible permutations of a vector containing two different values, in which I control the proportion of each of the values.

For example, if I have a vector of length three and I want all possible combinations containing a single 1, my desired output is a list looking like this:

```
list.1 <- list(c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0), c(0,0,1))
```

In contrast, if I want all possible combinations containing three 1s, my desired output is a list looking like this:

```
list.3 <- list(c(1,1,1))
```

To put it another way, the pattern of the `1` and `0` values matter, but all `1`s should be treated as identical to all other `1`s.

Based on searching here and elsewhere, I've tried several approaches:

```
expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1)  # this includes all possible combinations of 1, 2, or 3 ones
permn(c(0,1,1))             # this does not treat the ones as identical (e.g. it produces (0,1,1) twice)
unique(permn(c(0,1,1)))     # this does the job!
```

So, using the function `permn` from the package `combinat` seems promising. However, where I scale this up to my actual problem (a vector of length 20, with 50% 1s and 50% 0s, I run into problems:

```
unique(permn(c(rep(1,10), rep(0, 10))))

# returns the error:
Error in vector("list", gamma(n + 1)) : 
  vector size specified is too large
```

My understanding is that this is happening because, in the call to `permn`, it makes a list containing all possible permutations, even though many of them are identical, and this list is too large for R to handle.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to work around this?

Sorry if this has been answered previously - there are many, many SO questions containing similar language but different problems and I have not bene able to find a solution which meets my needs!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28368933/3184024) should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be a dealbreaker that `expand.grid` includes all permutations. Just add a subset after:

```
combinations <- function(size, choose) {

  d <- do.call("expand.grid", rep(list(0:1), size))
  d[rowSums(d) == choose,]

}

combinations(size=10, choose=3)
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10
# 8     1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# 12    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
# 14    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
# 15    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
# 20    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
# 22    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed that you are initially computing all factorial(20) (~10^18) permutations, which will not fit in your memory. 
What you are looking for is an efficient way to compute multiset permutations. The `multicool` package can do this:

```
library(multicool)

res <- allPerm(initMC(c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10) )))
```

This computation takes about two minutes on my laptop, but is definitely feasible.

Comment: This does not produce the desired output. Can you post `head(res)`?

Comment: This solution seemed to work for me; both produced 184,756 combinations with rowsums==10. However I selected Pierre's solution as ran in <1 second (as opposed to ~90 seconds on my computer).